# Value of series increasing by multiplication and then addition

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you find the value of any given term in a sequence where $X_1=1+(a+1)*a$ and $X_2=1+(1+(a+1)*a)*a$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you expanded out some of these terms completely? If yes, what do you get? If no, do it.

Comment: If this is a recursive sequence, write out and expand the first few terms and the pattern should become obvious. Finally, if required, prove it by induction.

Comment: There are only two terms given, so far. If you mean a recursive sequence with $X_0=a+1$ and $X_{n+1}=1+X_n*a$, you should say so (in your question, not in a comment).